# MSCaptcha Web.config httpHandler Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, recaptcha

I would like to use Recaptcha in my project and i have the following problem in my web.config file .

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" />
</httpHandlers>
<pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="cc1" assembly="MSCaptcha" namespace="MSCaptcha" />
    </controls>
</pages>
```

My error:

> HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
>
> An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
>
> Most likely causes:
>
> This application defines configuration in the system.web/httpHandlers section.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you are running your application in Integrated mode on IIS 7.0 or higher.

When running in Integrated mode, you should register your HTTP Handlers like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
        ....
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
<add name="CAPTCHAHandler" verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Regards,
Uros

Comment: Config Source:
   10:   <system.web>
   11: <system.webServer>
   12:      <httpHandlers>

Comment: Config Source:
   10:   <system.web>
   11: <system.webServer>
   12:      <httpHandlers>

Comment: put system.webServer element ouside of system.web element

Comment: Remove httpHandlers element from web.config and paste system.webServer element that i suggested before </configuration> and it must work.

Comment: I also tried the same and it worked for me, Thanks a lot.very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I can fix your problem:
u just add:

```html
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="CaptchaImage" verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
<!--after or not in <system.web></system.web>-->
```

`